# An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I'm trying to put to array my SQL query string but I encounter this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred

What is the possible problem I have?

```vb
Dim myList As ArrayList
Dim cnt As Integer
cnt = lvTrans.SelectedItems.Count
For values As Integer = 0 To cnt
    Dim vals1 = lvTrans.FocusedItem.SubItems(9).Text()
    sqlString2 = " UNION " & _
    "SELECT * FROM tbltransmital_mkk t INNER JOIN tbltransmital1_mkk t1 ON t.transmital_no = t1.transmital_no WHERE t.transmital_no='" & txtTrans.Text & _
    "' AND t1.autokey ='" & vals1 & "'"
    myList.Add(sqlString2)

Next
sqlString = sqlString1 & sqlString2
MsgBox(sqlString)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myList` is `Nothing`. You never create an instance (with `New`).

As there's no reason to use an `ArrayList` at all (except you're somehow forced to work with .Net 1.1 or something), better use a `List(Of String)` instead, e.g.:

```
Dim myList = New List(Of String) ' <-- create an instance with "New"
```

Comment: how can i get the value from array?

Comment: I don't know exactly what `how can i get the value from array` is supposed to mean but I guess you want to combine `sqlString1` with the bunch of `UNION` clauses you add to `myList`. You can do something like `sqlString = sqlString1 & String.Join(" ", myList)`.

Comment: yeah exactly :) im using visual basic 2003,  New List(Of String) & String.Join(" ", myList) doesn't work for me.

Comment: What a pity. But you can use `new ArrayList` and `String.Join(" ", myList.ToArray())`.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred another error LOL